# LISP How to remove element at certain index from a list

Tags: list, lisp, element

I'm trying to learn LISP. I got my way around functions and I wanted to test myself with some.

I was trying to write a function that can remove an element from a list in a given index.

This seems pretty straightforward, but I can't manage to do it.

Example: I have the list (20 8 13 10) and I want to remove the number at index 2.

How would I go about something like this?

Comment: From the Stackoverflow help: *Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very easy. This is the base case:

```
(remove-nth 0 '(2 3)) ; => (3)
```

And the default case:

```
(remove-nth 1 '(1 2 3))         ; ==
(cons 1 (remove-nth 0 '(2 3)))
```

The only thing left for you to do is to actually implement it!

There is a third case. What if the list is `nil`? In the strictest sense you cannot do the job and you should signal an error or perhaps there isn't anything to do so it's ok to then have it as a base case that evaluates to `'()` so that `(remove-nth 5 '(1 2)) ; ==> (1 2)`

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out on my own, eventually. But your answer is great